# spring security "param.error" in jsp page?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, jstl

Could you please explain where are the parameters `param.error` and `param.logout` variables come from in `login.jsp`?

I have used spring security with spring boot

```
<c:if test="${param.error != null}">
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
       Invalid username and password.
   </div>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
   <div class="alert alert-success">
       You have been logged out successfully.
   </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using JSTL incorrectly. "!=" will not work. If you want to do a not equals condition you have to use the "**ne**" keyword. Like so:

```
 <c:if test="${param.x ne param.y}">
```

But in your case, what you're looking for is this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.logout}">

<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
```

not empty works on empty and null variables.

To answer your question... Without showing any more code, it's not possible to know where your variables come from. Surely you are setting something in your servlets?

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you please give what information hold the "param" variable (attributes) ?

Comment: somewhere in one of your servlets you are setting a variable "param" of object type. i.e. -> request.setAttribute("param", paramObject);

Comment: you could be setting it in a .jsp file via JSTL also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security login for your implementation, then that might have been where this `param.error`, `param.logout` come from.

Please see for more detail explanation - https://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email